# div multiple float left stretch

Tags: html, width, css-float

I have someting like this:

```
<style>
 .putLeft
 {
   float: left;
 }
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some dynamic text
    </tr>
  </td>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="div_1" class="putLeft">1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4</div>
      <div id="div_2" class="putLeft">1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4</div>
      <div id="div_3" class="putLeft">1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4</div>
      <div id="div_4" class="putLeft">1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4</div>
      <div id="div_n" class="putLeft">1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The content of div_1, div_2... div_n are columns with dynamic width.

What I want is something like this:

```
|some text with dynamic width and can be very long text|
-------------------------------------------------------
|    div1   |      div2    |     div3    |     div4   |
|    1      |        2     |       2     |      4     |
|    1      |        2     |       2     |      4     |



But my result is something like this:

|some text with dynamic with and can be very long text|
-------------------------------------------------------
| div1 | div2 | div3 | div4 |
|  1   |   2  |   2  |   4  |
|  1   |   2  |   2  |   4  |
```

How can I put the "float: left" columns to stretch to maximum width?

Note: There is no fixed width in the whole example. And I can not make a table to put the div's content.

Edit: Inserted some content on divs. I did put some 
 to make the example simple. But it will will have other contents.

Comment: the amount of div's is also unknown while design time and you are not willing to use JavaScript?

Comment: You shouldn't have to use JavaScript though :) I would recommend trying to get a solution that's pure CSS for obvious reasons. Also, the mark-up above is invalid.  I created a fiddle for you below w/ correct mark-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery example would be:

Html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some dynamic text
    </tr>
  </td>
  <tr>
    <td id="row">
      <div id="div_1" class="putLeft"></div>
      <div id="div_2" class="putLeft"></div>
      <div id="div_3" class="putLeft"></div>
      <div id="div_4" class="putLeft"></div>
      <div id="div_n" class="putLeft"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.putLeft
 {
   float: left;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ffcc33;
 }

table { width: 100% }
```

JS with jQuery

```
$(function() {
   var count = $('#row div').length;
   $('#row div').each( function(index, item) {
       $(item).css('width', Math.floor(100 / count) + '%');
   });
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qdnvq/

This can be made far more accurate by retrieving the width in 'px' from the outer `<td>` and then calulating pixel widths for the div's and maybe make the last one as large to bypass the missing space from rounding. Also you may use absolute positioning instead of floating.

Comment: don't get me wrong, I like your solution.  I just save jQuery as a last resort to modify layout, that way the page can downgrade gracefully for other platforms, etc...

Comment: @pixelbobby I'am absolutely in line with you, to avoid JS where it is possible, but i don't see another solution in this case. It would be great, if someone could show me a CSS only way.

Comment: Going to use this solution for now.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I started a fiddle for you and corrected your mark-up: http://jsfiddle.net/yHrZx/
Can you provide more HTML to it so we can help you with the CSS.  **Avoid JavaScript Solution for this at all costs...**

Comment: How should a CCS only solution look like with floting div's and unknown width?

Comment: I have filled columns with come content. Think with that you can have a better idea.